# Create audio buffer from server

Tags: node.js

Got to build a server from scratch that takes a audio file and sends it over a stream to multiple end-users. I have looked into streams and buffers and have some basic idea about sending text data via buffers to client-side but in my scenario, I also need to start playing the audio when the buffer is received at the user end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the way to send audio as streams:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fileSystem = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var filePath = 'read.mp3';
    var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });
    

    var readStream = fileSystem.createReadStream(filePath,{ highWaterMark: 1 * 16 });

readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
 response.write(chunk);
});
    console.log("Serving");

})
.listen(2000);
```

Comment: Thats bad, you should pipe the stream instead to `res`

Comment: @Marc if you use pipe, the result is the same. Wonder what difference would it make.

Comment: When you listen for the "data" event you switch to "flow mode" and send chunks to the client regardless if he is able to process the data. In "pause mode" the client can control the speed of the stream if needed: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_two_reading_modes